# How do I search and replace with a regex and preserve blank spaces in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using this code:
`$text =~ s/\s(\w)/\u$1/g;`

But `This is an example`

Become `ThisIsAnExample`

Instead of `This Is An Example`.

How to preserve blank spaces?

Comment: Try removing `\s` and adding a `+` : `$text =~ s/(\w+)/\u$1/g;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lookbehind.

```
$text =~ s/(?<!\S)(\w)/\u$1/g;
```

Or use the more efficient `\K` (Perl 5.10+).

```
$text =~ s/(?:^|\s)\K(\w)/\u$1/g;
```

Both of the solutions will make sure the first word is capitalized too. If that's not an issue, the second solution can be simplified to the following:

```
$text =~ s/\s\K(\w)/\u$1/g;
```

Comment: This is the best answer since i can ignore more characters instead of spaces-only.

Answer (score 1):

The matching contains the whitespace, the replacement doesn't.

```
$text =~ s/(\s)(\w)/$1\u$2/g;
```

Since `\s` contains different types of whitespace characters, if you want to keep it in your replacement, you need to capture it and put it back.

An alternative is to use word boundaries and full "words".

```
$text =~ s/\b(\w+)\b/\u$1/g;
```